# Proof that if f(a)<0 and f(b)>0 f and is continuous on [a,b] then f changes sign at some c in (a,b)

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, roots

In Calculus, people argue that if $f(a)<0$ and $f(b)>0$, then IVT guarantees that $f(x)$ changes sign at some point in $(a,b)$. I understand that IVT guarentees that there is a $c$ such that $f(c)=0$. I was able to prove using the bisection method that there is a $c\in (a,b)$ such that $f$ changes sign at $c$ in the sense that $\forall \delta>0$, $\exists x\in (c,c+\delta)$, $f(x)<0$ and $\exists x\in (c,c+\delta)$, $f(x)>0$.

Assuming that $f(a)<0$ and $f(b)>0$ and $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, I would like to show that there is some point $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f$ changes sign from negative to positive in the sense that $\exists \delta_1>0, \forall x\in(c-\delta_1,c),\ f(x)<0$ and $\exists \delta_2>0$, $\forall x\in(c,c+\delta_2), \ f(x)>0$. I am surprised that no textbook has proven this even though it is a crucial result in Calculus.

I know that the sense of changing sign in paragraph 1 is not equivalent to the sense in paragraph 2, as

$f(x)=\begin{cases}
xsin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right),  & \text{if $x\ne0$} \\
0, & \text{if $x=0$}
\end{cases}$

satisfies the definition of changing sign in the first paragraph but not the definition of changing sign in the second paragraph.

I tried arguing by contradiction, assuming that $f$ does not change sign from positive to negative at any point in $(a,b)$. Then $\forall c\in (a,b)$, either $\forall \delta_1>0, \exists x\in(c-\delta_1,c),\ f(x)\ge 0$ **or** $\exists \delta_2>0$, $\exists x\in(c,c+\delta_2), \ f(x)\le0$.

The problem is that I don't know how to deal with the or in bold. I have been able to prove that assuming $\forall c\in (a,b)$ $\forall \delta_1>0, \exists x\in(c-\delta_1,c),\ f(x)\ge 0$ results in a contradiction, but this is not what I was trying to prove was false.

Comment: "there is a c such that f(c)" is meaningless.

Comment: @Andrew Murdza Did you mean to say $f (c)=0$?

Comment: Yes. I just realized that what I am trying to prove could be false if f=0 on some subinterval of [a,b].

Comment: There appears to be a subscript error in pp2.  Correcting that, changing sign in pp1 and pp2 are equivalent.  Just use the smaller delta.

Comment: I was trying to prove this theorem to prove another theorem, if f'(a)<0 and f'(b)>0, and f is continuously differentiable on (a,b), then f has a strict local minmum at some c in (a,b). It seems to me that theorem is also false.

Comment: Proposition requires positive f'(c).  @AndrewMurdza

Comment: Thanks Elliot. This answers my question.

Comment: Theorem requires f is nowhere locally constant.

Comment: If I replace strict local minimum with local minimum, then it would be true, because then if f is locally contstant we would have that every point in the interior of that locally constant region is a relative minimum. Proving that f has a strict local minimum if f is nowhere constant seems equivalent to proving the original question if f is never locally 0. Could you give me a hint on how to prove it this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have the following stronger result:

> **Theorem (Strong IVT)**: Let $f:[a, b] \to\mathbb {R} $ be a function which is continuous on $[a, b] $ such that $f(a) f(b) <0$. Then there exist two points $c, d$ in $(a, b)$ such that $c\leq d, f(c) =f(d) =0$ and $f(x) $ maintains a constant sign in $[a, c) $ and in $(d, b] $. In other words there is a first and a last value of $x$ in $[a, b] $ for which $f(x) =0$.

To prove it consider set $$A=\{x\in[a, b] \mid f\text{ maintains a constant sign in }[a, x] \}$$ The set $A$ is bounded above by $b$ and includes all points of interval $[a, a+h] $ for some $h>0$. It follows that $c=\sup A$ exists and $a<c\leq b$. Similarly for set $B$ defined by $$B=\{x\in[a, b] \mid f\text{ maintains a constant sign in }[x, b] \} $$ $d=\inf B$ exists and $a\leq d<b$. It can further be proved that $c, d$ satisfy all the properties in conclusion of the theorem (prove this!).

If $c=d$ then you can see the sign change happening at $c$ in exactly the way you want. But this is not guaranteed all the time. For example if $f(x) =1-x$ for $0\leq x\leq 1$,$f(x)=0$ for $1<x<2$ and $f(x) =2-x$ for $2\leq x\leq 3$ then $f(0)f(3)<0$ and yet no sign change occurs at a single point.

Comment: This Perfect!!! This is exactly what I wanted!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there a general situation where c=d? I see that it is not necessarily true if f is constant on some subinterval of [a,b]. How could I use the theorem to prove that $x^2sin(\frac{1}{x})$ for $x\ne 0$, $0$ for $x=0$ changes sign at some point in [-1,1]? I see how iteratively applying Strong IVT would give me that any function with finitely many zeros changes sign in they the way I want.

Comment: @AndrewMurdza: the case $c=d$ happens only when there is a single root of $f(x) =0$ in $(a, b) $. A sufficient condition for this is that $f$ is strictly monotone.

Comment: @AndrewMurdza: for your function you need derivatives : $f'(x) =2x\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x)$. The roots of $f(x) $ are $x=0,x=1/(n\pi),n\in\mathbb{Z},n\neq 0$. Check the derivative at these points. If $f(a) =0,f'(a)\neq 0$ then $f$ changes sign at $a$ in the manner you expect.

Comment: @AndrewMurdza: also try to prove the result I stated at the end of my previous comment.

Comment: Perhaps if there are countably many zeros then I could construct a sequence $c_n$ and $d_n$ such that $c_n\le c_{n+1} \le d_{n+1} \le d_n$. $c_n$ and $d_n$ both converge to the same limit c. Arguing by contradiction, I can assume that $f$ does not change sign from at any of the $c_n$'s or any of the $d_n$'s in which case I would have f is positive on [a,c) and negative on (c,b], so $f$ does change sign at $c$.

Comment: Sorry I didn't send your other messages

Comment: I think that it is true that if the set of zeros of $f$ is uncountable then the zeros would be dense in some subinterval of $[a,b]$. If this is the case, I was able to prove that if the zeros of $f$ are dense on some subset and $f$ is continuous, then $f$ is identically zero on that subset. In that case I will have proven that $f$ must change sign if $f$ is not $0$ on some subinterval of $[a,b]$