# Change of Sign Of Continuous Function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Prove that if there is a continuous function $f(x)$ such that $f(a)<0$ and $f(b)>0$ then there exists a $a<c<b$ such that $$f(c)=0$$ and $f(x)$ does not change sign in any of the intervals $(c-\delta, c)$ and $(c, c+\delta)$ for some $\delta>0$ but $f(x)$ has opposite signs on these intervals.

Note that the intermediate value theorem implies the existence of $c$ such that $f(c) = 0$.

As suggested in the comment, there are continuous functions $f$ with $c$ such that $f(c)=0$ but $f$ is not of fixed sign on both side. For example, given the function

\begin{align}
f: (-1, 1) \to \mathbb R,\ \ \ \ \ \ f(x) = \begin{cases} x\sin \frac 1x, & \text{ if } x\neq 0, \\ 0 & \text{ if } x=0 \end{cases} 
\end{align}

then $f(0) = 0$ but we cannot find such $\delta$. But we can find another $c\neq 0$ with that property.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem#:~:text=In%20mathematical%20analysis%2C%20the%20intermediate,some%20point%20within%20the%20interval.&text=The%20image%20of%20a%20continuous,interval%20is%20itself%20an%20interval.

Comment: I am not asking about IVT, plz read the question carefully

Comment: Consider $f(x)=x\sin\frac{1}{x}$ for $x\not=0$ and $f(0)=0$.

Comment: This function has the above property

Comment: Please find that $\delta$.

Comment: But in your example you haven't given $a$ and $b$ as mentioned in the question

Comment: Take $a=-\epsilon$ and $b=\delta$ where $\epsilon,\delta$ are suitable positives.

Comment: Almost. Take $a = -\frac 2 {3\pi}$ and $b= \frac2\pi$.

Comment: Chose $c=\frac{1}{4π}$ and chose $\delta$ sufficiently close to $\frac{1}{4π}$

Comment: Chose $\delta=\frac{1}{25π}$

Comment: Zoom it as long as you want to find such $\delta$.           https://www.geogebra.org/classic/ssgkmepa

Comment: I proved that the function you gave in your example has the above property

Comment: Nice. Write your proof then.

Comment: Whenever $x$ lies in the interval $(\frac{1}{4π}, \frac{1}{4π}+\frac{1}{25π})$ then it is easy to show that $\frac{1}{x}$ lies in $(3π, 4π)$ and hence $xsin(\frac{1}{x})$ is negative in this interval. Similarly we can show that when $x$ lies in the interval $(\frac{1}{4π}-\frac{1}{25π}, \frac{1}{4π})$ then $xsin(\frac{1}{x})$ is positive and hence the function has the above property

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof that if f(a)<0 and f(b)>0 f and is continuous on \[a,b\] then f changes sign at some c in (a,b)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2994771/proof-that-if-fa0-and-fb0-f-and-is-continuous-on-a-b-then-f-changes-sign)

Comment: @player3236 the strong form of IVT proves the case when there are finitely many roots of $f(x)$ on $(a, b)$ and not the case when $f(x)$ has infinitely many roots in the interval $(a, b)$

Comment: @player3236 the strong form of IVT proves the case when there are finitely many roots of $f(x)$ on $(a, b)$ and not the case when $f(x)$ has infinitely many roots in the interval $(a, b)$

Comment: @user763338: By "opposite signs" do you mean _strictly_ opposite?

Comment: Yes I mean strictly opposite

Comment: So a counterexample would be a continuous function with no isolated zeros. This smells like a cantor set example. (A cantorexample, if you will.)

Answer (score 4):

Quasi gives a good counterexample to the question as asked, but we can also find a counterexample that is nonconstant on every open interval of $[a,b]$.

Let $f_0$ be the zero function on $[0,1]$. Define a sequence $f_k$ by, at the $k{th}$ step in the construction of the ternary cantor set, adding triangle functions supported on the removed intervals, scaled by $(-1)^{k+1}$.

(By "triangle function" I mean a function defined on an interval $I$ such that the union of $I\times\{0\}$ with its graph is an equilateral triangle.)

The sequence $f_k$ will converge to some continuous $f$. Choose $a,b$ such that $f(a) < 0$ and $f(b) > 0$. The zero set of $f$ is the restriction of the ternary Cantor set to $[a,b]$. As this is a perfect set, the function $f$ has no isolated zeros, and because between any two zeros $f$ changes sign, it will change sign infinitely often in any neighborhood of any zero.

Comment: My revised post was worked out independently, but it's clear that it's in the same spirit as your answer. Plus 1 for yours.

Answer (score 1):

For an easy counterexample, let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined by
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x+1&\text{if}\;x < -1\\[4pt]
0&\text{if}\;-1 \le x \le 1\\[4pt]
x-1&\text{if}\;x > 1\\[4pt]
\end{cases}
$$
and let $a=-2,b=2$.

But suppose we require that $f$ is not identically zero on any open interval?

With that additional assumption, I think the following will still yield a counterexample . . .

Let $C$ denote the Cantor set, and let $J=[0,1]{\setminus}C$

For each $x\in J$, let $s(x)=(-1)^n$, where $n$ is the number of digits before the first digit of $1$ in the ternary representation of $x$.

Since $C$ is closed, for all $x\in J$, the distance $d(x,C)$ is positive.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined by
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x&\text{if}\;x < 0\\[4pt]
0&\text{if}\;x \in C\\[4pt]
s(x)d(x,C)&\text{if}\;x\in J\\[4pt]
x-1&\text{if}\;x >1\\
\end{cases}
$$
and let $a=-1,b=2$.

Then there does not exist $c\in (a,b)$ satisfying the specified conditions.

Comment: But what is the function is not constant on any interval

Comment: It's a good question.

Comment: Can you give the proof when the function is not constant

Comment: I'll think about it . . .

Comment: Both of these counterexamples are well done, +1 to your answer